# MAVEN SUREFIRE PLUGIN ERROR

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

Im building a custom maven project for jenkins. After using the command

```
   mvn -Plight-test install
```

I recieve this error .Please help. I have also added the plugin for surefire exception in the `pom.xml` file, but it isn't working! The error log is as follows :

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Jenkins main module ................................ SUCCESS [ 11.809 s]
    [INFO] Jenkins cli ........................................ SUCCESS [ 38.319 s]
    [INFO] Jenkins core ....................................... FAILURE [11:15 min]
    [INFO] Jenkins war ........................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Tests for Jenkins core ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 12:10 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-05T12:26:54+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 39M/277M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project jenkins-core:
    .
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Anishas\git\jenkins\core\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :jenkins-core
```

[image]

Compile :
[image]

Comment: "Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging."

Comment: @Lee thank you for the suggestion. But how do I recognize the defect as the output is too large?

Comment: Well, you can't see very much from what you have posted other than the failure is in jenkins-core.  Run with -X and you will have to manually drill down to the appropriate area.  If you run mvn -rf jenkins-core -X that will restart the build from the failure point.

Comment: You should first fix all those warnings and error before doing something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests=true clean install
```

use this command

Comment: this is wrong! you are not supposed to skip tests to fix stuff

Comment: skipping test is not resolving problems.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues and I found out that the problem was that some of tests tried to create a System link and it was not possible because I didn't start my IDE (IntellijIdea) as administrator in Windows. 
I started Intellij as administrator and that solved the problem.

Skipping test is not a good practice when developing.

Comment: After a few days of research, this actually was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rerun with `mvn -Plight-test install -rf jenkins-core -X` to isolate the error

Comment: says this :[ERROR] [ERROR] Could not find project to resume reactor build from: jenkins-core vs [MavenProject: org.jenkins-ci.main:pom:2.2-

Comment: sorry you need to add your build goals as well.

Comment: could you please tell how do i do that?? @Lee

Comment: How is your project structured?  Do you have a parent pom.xml file?  Or is it just a collection of siblings?  I think you have a reference to a project called jenkins-core that doesn't exist

Comment: collection of siblings

Comment: What is the output if you just try to build `mvn clean compile -pl jenkins-core`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111095/discussion-between-learner-and-lee).